# Change Product Price That effects the price range in Layerd Navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, price, collection, layered-navigation, product-collection

I change the product price by custom rules in custom module. By the Event `<catalog_product_collection_load_after>`
for product list page. And for product view page I override the `getPrice()` Method of the
`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price`.

My Problem is that price is changed according to the custom rules. But Price slider range is not updated. I also rewrite the layer model and prepareProductCollection() function but nothing change in price range. Price slider is still works on the product price. Not on my custom price. My question is how to change the product price that it effects price ranges. I not want to save the price in product table. I want to change the price like Magento Catalog Rule Change the Price.
[image]

Comment: Have you Re-index Price after Applying Rules?

Comment: Yes i reindex the Product Price After Apply my custom rules but no luck

Comment: something is wrong bro. I have never seen this kind of error lets some one else guide you.

Comment: Bro This is my custom module and i change the product prices using the events mentioned in my question. And also i am not save the product prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only made the adjustments for loaded product collections and single products.

The normal prices are still in the price index, which is used directly by the layered navigation.

Catalog price rules change the price index as well and you need to do the same. Have a look into the `CatalogRule` module to see how it is done.

#### The following events are observed:

- `prepare_catalog_product_price_index_table` to save the custom price in the price index during reindexing
- `catalog_product_save_commit_after` to update index after product has been saved
- `catalog_product_import_finish_before` and `catalog_product_import_after` to apply rules after import
- `prepare_catalog_product_collection_prices` to load price rules by date, product, website and customer group for loaded product collection. Stores it for later use in other observer:
- `catalog_product_get_final_price` to adjust the price on product page, cart and during checkout
- `catalog_entity_attribute_delete_after` and `catalog_entity_attribute_save_after` to update/deactivate rules that use deleted or change attributes (probably not necessary for your custom module)

That being said, I would try to use and extend the `CatalogRule` module instead of reinventing it. It will be simpler to implement custom actions and conditions and leave all the complex indexing logic to the core module.